# Listbox Item Clearing is Not Working in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, listboxitem

I have a two list boxes with one button when the user can click the button move all the list item from listbox1 to listbox2. when the listbox1 is becomes empty app is getting restarted IN EXCEL 2016.

My Code is

```
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MultiSheet").ListBoxes(strFromlb).listCount
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MultiSheet").ListBoxes(strTolb).AddItem ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MultiSheet").ListBoxes(strFromlb).List(1)
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MultiSheet").ListBoxes(strFromlb).RemoveItem (1)
Next i
```

Here `strFromLb` is clearing the values but when it clearing last value my VBA App is excel has been restarted.

Then I have tried code to clear the listbox

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MultiSheet").ListBoxes(strFromlb).ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MultiSheet").ListBoxes(strFromlb).Items.Clear
```

The error is

> "Object doesnt supported to property or method"

Then

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MultiSheet").ListBoxes(strFromlb).Clear
```

This code I got the 400 error. so kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("MultiSheet").ListBoxes(strFromlb).ControlFormat.‌​RemoveAllItems
```

Comment: Clear function is not an property or method

Comment: try accessing listbox by their name (ie. strFromlb.Clear), not with the function Listboxes("...")

Comment: Still facing same error only i have tried with name

Comment: Object doesnt supported to property or method

Comment: are you doing this in userforms? or what?

Comment: Excel form controls

Comment: I see. Try: Worksheets("MultiSheet").ListBoxes(strFromlb).ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems

Comment: I tried this one also see my question itself i mentioned its also not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127758/discussion-between-cullan-and-dinesh-dinaz).

Answer (score 0):

**Reference:** [The Complete Guide to Excel VBA Form Control ListBoxes](http://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/complete-guide-to-excel-vba-form-control-listboxes/)

There are two type listbox controls for the worksheet Forms control and MsForms ActiveX control. `getListBox` will return get either one.

You code has a couple of syntax errors in it

- `Listbox.List` returns a 0 based array
- You don't use parentheses when using `RemoveItem` because it is a not a function

---

```
Dim lBoxFrom As Object, lBoxTo As Object

Set lBoxFrom = getListBox("MultiSheet", strFromlb)
Set lBoxTo = getListBox("MultiSheet", strTolb)

For i = 0 To lBoxFrom.ListCount - 1
    lBoxTo.AddItem lBoxFrom.List(1)
    lBoxFrom.RemoveItem 1
Next
```

or

```
lBoxTo.List = lBoxFrom.List
lBoxFrom.Clear
```

---

```
Sub Test()
    Const WORKSHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"
    Const strFromlb = "BoxFrom"
    Const strTolb = "BoxTo"

    Dim lBoxFrom As Object, lBoxTo As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Set lBoxFrom = getListBox(WORKSHEET_NAME, strFromlb)
    Set lBoxTo = getListBox(WORKSHEET_NAME, strTolb)
    lBoxFrom.AddItem "A"
    lBoxFrom.AddItem "B"
    lBoxFrom.AddItem "C"

    For i = 0 To lBoxFrom.ListCount - 1
        lBoxTo.AddItem lBoxFrom.List(0)
        lBoxFrom.RemoveItem 0
    Next

End Sub

Function getListBox(WorkSheetName As String, ListBoxName As String) As Object
    Dim lBox As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set lBox = Worksheets(WorkSheetName).ListBoxes(ListBoxName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If lBox Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set lBox = Worksheets(WorkSheetName).Shapes(ListBoxName).OLEFormat.Object.Object
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    Set getListBox = lBox
End Function
```

Comment: you'r missing a `Set getListBox = lBox` at the end of the function. More over I'd shorten it down to `Function GetListBox(WorkSheetName As String , ListBoxName As String) As Object/ Dim lBox As Object/ On Error Resume Next/  Set lBox = Worksheets(WorkSheetName).ListBoxes(ListBoxName)/ If lBox Is Nothing Then Set lBox = Worksheets(WorkSheetName).Shapes(ListBoxName).OLEFormat.Object/ On Error GoTo 0/ Set GetListBox = lBox/ End Function`

Comment: Thanks again @user3598756.  I've been rushing too much lately.

Comment: Ya but still the is worksheet restarting when the listboxes is empty

Comment: Its not showing any error message. this line is executing fine lBoxFrom.RemoveItem 1 but when it remove last item in our listbox then its showing that microsoft oexcel is crashed and microsoft excel is restarting.

Comment: @DineshDinaz I updated my answer.  There were two problems.  1) I needed `.Object.Object` to reference the listbox object itself.  2) it should be `lBoxFrom.RemoveItem 0` because the listbox's List is 0 based.